# Android OAuth Retrofit Access Token Request

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, retrofit

Can anyone tell the exact format to convert below code into retrofit

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin&scope=read+write" -u"clientId:clientSecret" http://myserver/o/token/
```

I have tried something like this but it isn't working

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/o/token/")
AccessTokenResponse getToken(@Field("client_id") String client_id, @Field("client_secret") String client_secret,
    @Field("grant_type") String grant_type, @Field("username") String username,
    @Field("password") String password, @Field("scope") String scope);
```

Comment: 401 Unauthorized error is being raised !!

Comment: Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges
401 Unauthorized error is being raised !!

Comment: Retrofit 1 or Retrofit 2?

Answer (score 8):

Client credentials should be authenticated with [Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). i.e with header

```
Authorization: Basic base64encode(clientId:clientSecret)
```

where `base64encode(clientId:clientSecret)` is the actual base64 encoded string of `clientId:clientSecret`. So to update your interface it might look something more like

```
public interface OAuthTokenService {

    @POST("/api/token")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @Headers({
        "Accept: application/json"
    })
    AccessTokenResponse getAccessToken(@Field("grant_type") String grantType,
                                       @Field("username") String username,
                                       @Field("password") String password,
                                       @Header("Authorization") String authorization);    
}
```

Then to set the header, do something like

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setEndpoint("http://localhost:8080")
                .setConverter(new JacksonConverter())
                .build();

        OAuthTokenService service = restAdapter.create(OAuthTokenService.class);
        byte[] credentials = "clientId:clientSecret".getBytes();
        String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(credentials);

        AccessTokenResponse response = service
                .getAccessToken("password", "admin", "admin", basicAuth);
        System.out.println(response.getAccessToken());
    }
}
```

Note the above uses Java 8 for the `java.util.Base64` class. You may not be using Java 8, in which case you will need to find a different encoder.

I am also using Jackson for conversion, only because I don't use Gson. The above has been tested and should work for you also.

Comment: What type of object is `AccessTokenResponse`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky it's made up. It should have all the properties that come in the response. Its just a POJO just like you would handle any other JSON response.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha, could you please update with Retrofit 2?

Answer (score 6):

With OkHttp interceptors this is made easier.

```
Interceptor interceptor = chain -> {
        Request original = chain.request();
        Request request = original.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", Credentials.basic(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET))
                .method(original.method(), original.body())
                .build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    };

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build();

return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseURL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

The Credentials.basic method will base 64 encode your client id and client secret. The interceptor is then attached to the **OkHttpClient** client and added to the **Retrofit** object.